Reference for global implicit function theorem in any dimensions
In the book Advanced Calculus 2E by Patrick M. Fitzpatrick, I found the global implicit function theorem  in 1 dimension:
Suppose that the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and that there is a positive number $c$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) \geq c \quad \text{for every} \, (x, y) \, \text{in} \, \mathbb{R}^2.
$$
Then there is a continuously differentiable function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with
$$
f(x, g(x)) = 0 \quad \text{for every} \, x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
and that if $f(x, y) = 0$, then $y = g(x)$.
I am looking for a general version for the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+ m} \to \mathbb{R}^m$. We can simply assume that for any $x$, there is $y$ such that $f(x, y) = 0$. I have searched the keyword global implicit function but do not find a related result.

Perhaps try the Krantz-Parks text discussed here. I do not have access to it to look myself.

Theorem 1 here and the proofs in the paper might interest you

Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (chapter 9) contains this theorem. In my copy of the 3rd edition, this is on pages 224-225.

Thanks for the reference, but I think it is not a global one?
